# In plain English, what is an object model?

Tags: object-oriented

I read [about objects models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_model) on Wikipedia, but it is too abstract to really make much sense to me. Can someone explain what an object model is in plain English?

Comment: A model of your problem space using classes (or objects). How's that? We also talk about "data model" as how you model your problem space in the database, although it overlaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our purposes an *Object* is a thing or concept and a *Model* is a representation of the parts you need to refer to in your design/code.

An **Interface** is a description of what of what we need to know/do in our design/code.

For example: a `Vehicle` object model might be an interface which requires:-

**Properties** to represent the state of the object (capacity, speed, direction)

**Methods** which affect those properties (load/unload, go faster/slower, turn)

**Exceptions** that represent errors which may occur (collision, breakdown, no fuel)

That interface is then implemented as a **class** and the code might differ for a `Hovercraft` compared to a `Car` but for the code which needs to operate the vehicle, it should not need to know about those things.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of object models:

- for a programming language, it is the characteristics of objects in that language.  Three examples of those characteristics, there are others:

  - is there a notion of multiple inheritance or not (if present, there are more questions to answer, is it limited to something like interface or more general like in C++, what happens in case of apparent ambiguity: error like in C++ or a resolution algorithm like in Common Lisp, which resolution algorithm is also important)
  - are method's validity checked statically (how? with an inheritance mechanism or something else) or dynamically (what happens if there is no method of that name? an error? is forwarding possible?)
  - are those characteristic ad hoc or do they have a theoretical foundation?  Which? (Cardelli's Object Calculus?  Something else?)

  The object model is somewhat independent of the programming language.  Languages targeting Microsoft's CLR tend to have a more similar object models than others as the classes are designed with a model in mind.  You may even have languages with several object models. C++/CLI has two, the C++ one and the CLR one.  Objective C++ is another language with two object models: the C++ one and the Objective C one (which is nearer to the one of SmallTalk)
- a (more or less standardized) set of classes representing something (documents, telescope, ...).  I won't write more about that, it is just a modelization based on classes and objects.